# Fluxcd ImageRepository authentication with AWS Elastic Container Registry Not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, arm64, gitops, fluxcd

`Fluxcd` `ImageRepository` authentication with `AWS Elastic Container Registry` Not working on `ARM64 graviton` node.

After debugging I found that the image used in the `init container` to get cred credentials is not supporting `Arm64` instances.

```
image name:-bitnami/kubectl
```

**doc link:-https://fluxcd.io/docs/guides/image-update/**

Answer (score 3):

There are some workarounds, provided on the `fluxcd` documentation portal:

- [AWS Elastic Container Registry](https://fluxcd.io/docs/guides/image-update/#aws-elastic-container-registry)
- [Using a JSON key](https://fluxcd.io/docs/guides/image-update/#using-a-json-key-long-lived)
- [Using Static Credentials](https://fluxcd.io/docs/guides/image-update/#using-static-credentials-long-lived)

## AWS Elastic Container Registry

> The solution proposed is to create a cronjob that runs every 6 hours which would re-create the `docker-registry` secret using a new token.

## JSON key

> A Json key doesn’t expire, so we don’t need a cronjob, we just need to create the secret and reference it in the ImagePolicy.
> First, create a json key file by following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication). Grant the service account the role of `Container Registry Service Agent` so that it can access GCR and download the json file.

## Static Credentials

> Instead of creating the Secret directly into your Kubernetes cluster, encrypt it using [Mozilla SOPS](https://fluxcd.io/docs/guides/mozilla-sops/) or [Sealed Secrets](https://fluxcd.io/docs/guides/sealed-secrets/), then commit and push the encypted file to git.

> This Secret should be in the same Namespace as your flux `ImageRepository` object. Update the `ImageRepository.spec.secretRef` to point to it.

Comment: Thanks .. @Yasen .. issue fixed by fluxcd ...just the image it should work.                     https://github.com/fluxcd/flux2/issues/1864

Comment: Glad to help you

Comment: hey @Yasen after changing image  bitnami/kubectl to ghcr.io/fluxcd/flux-cli:v0.17.2 (multi-arch-image of flux).. secret created but still not able to authenticate with ECR.. Beacuse this command `kubectl create secret docker-registry $SECRET_NAME \
                --dry-run=client \
                --docker-server="$ECR_REGISTRY" \
                --docker-username=AWS \
                --docker-password="$(</token/ecr-token)" \
                -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -`       having some issue to fetch token using this "$(</token/ecr-token)" and /token/ecr-token is file.. any idea.plz